# React Testing Library: waitFor vs act

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, react-testing-library

I have an async method that changes the state by callback:

```
class Demo{
  callback: () => void;
    
  async triggerCallback() {
    this.callback();
  }

}
```

This callback is being used to hide/show an element:

```
const DemoComponent: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({Demo}) =>{
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const changeStateCallback = () => {
    setState(true);
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
   Demo.callback = changeStateCallback;
  }, []);

  
  return(
    <>
      {show && <p>Foo</p>}
    </>
  )
};
```

I now want to test this and I'm still learning testing with Jest and React Testing Library, so at first I had:

```
it("test", async () => {
  const Demo = new Demo();

  render(<DemoComponent Demo={Demo}/>);

  await Demo.triggerCallback();

  expect(screen.queryByText("Foo")).toBeTruthy();
}
```

And this failed because it complained that Demo.triggerCallback(); had to be wrapped in an act():

> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
>
> act(() => {
> /* fire events that update state */
> });
> /* assert on the output */

Which I did with the async/await rules:

```
it("test", async () => {
  const Demo = new Demo();

  render(<DemoComponent Demo={Demo}/>);

  await act( async () =>{
      await Demo.triggerCallback();
  };

  expect(screen.queryByText("Foo")).toBeTruthy();
}
```

It failed again saying I couldn't make act async:

> Warning: The callback passed to ReactTestUtils.act(...) function must
> not return anything.
>
> It looks like you wrote ReactTestUtils.act(async () => ...), or
> returned a Promise from the callback passed to it. Putting
> asynchronous logic inside ReactTestUtils.act(...) is not supported.

After some research in the docs and google, I found this waitFor() method but together with expect, e.g.:

```
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

But for sake of it, I replaced act() for waitFor() since it's one of the few async methods I found in the react testing library. Final look (I wrapped it in a try/catch just in case):

```
it("test", async () => {
  const Demo = new Demo();

  render(<DemoComponent Demo={Demo}/>);
  
  try {
    await waitFor( async () =>{
        await Demo.triggerCallback();
    };
  } catch(e) {
    fail("Test failed": + e);
  }

  expect(screen.queryByText("Foo")).toBeTruthy();
}
```

And the test passes! Now... is this correct? Just because it works I'm unsure of the solution so would like some feedback on this. I feel I'm doing something illegal because I could only find waitFor() examples with expect() and nothing else.

Comment: I think you are violating React's one-way data binding practice. What is the reason you are trying to manipulate React's component state from the vanilla Javascript class?

Comment: I have an API for server/client communication in vanilla JS and when I get an error from the server I want to display a popup.

Comment: Shota has a point. When your vanilla communication API errors, it could pass a prop to the `DemoComponent`, perhaps? Or you could build a hook that bridges your vanilla JS API so you can use it within React.

Comment: It feels like you are trying to test two things in one, the Class Demo behaviour and the Component DemoComponent behaviour. Testing DemoComponent would be testing the text appearance in the sreen once component is prepared. 'act' is used for preparation and if you look at recipies in the docs, you'd see an example of rendering component in the act. If calling a class is a trigger then it would be smth like this:
act(() => {render(<DemoComponent demo={new Demo()} />, container);});
And then you wait for Foo with 
await waitFor(() => {expect(getByText('Foo')).toBeInTheDocument()})